# How can I properly sanitize the update_option in WordPress?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization, sanitization

I am using this part of the code in my WordPress plugin to update the option.

```
update_option('button_loc_shop_page', $_POST['button_loc_shop_page']);
```

I want to sanitize this. How can I properly sanitize it? Any comments or pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: [Register your setting](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/) and you can define the callback function that receives the data during the saving operation.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to do that, but couldn't find the way to sanitize it, because here the updat_option is using a POST request as a value. So, not quite sure how can I do that. Can you please share a rough line of code on how can I achieve that? Thanks!!

Comment: There's an answer posted with a link to sanitization functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sanitize the data with sanitize functions in reference below.

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-input/